# Prolog Error Catching

Tags: prolog

Given:

```
fruitid('Apple', 'Granny Smith', 1).
fruitid('Pear', 'Bartlett', 2).
```

If I had the clause

```
type_of_fruit(ID):-
       fruitid(Fruit, _, ID), write(Fruit).
```

How could I implement a method to catch erroneous inputs?

For instance

```
fruitid(5).
```

Thanks.

AS

Answer (score 6):

Set Prolog Flags and Use Catch/3

Assuming SWI Prolog

1) The prolog_flags can change error behavior.
First allow the system to catch the error and report it. The `unknown` flag is for unknown predicates such as `fruitID/1`.

```
set_prolog_flag(report_error,true).
set_prolog_flag(unknown,error).
```

Now when the wrong predicate arity is used, there should be an error message like this:

```
?- fruitid(5).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: fruitid/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

2) To trap exceptions such as this in code,
Wrap the goal in a catch/3 predicate. 
The settigs from 1) are stil required.
This is the way to trap undefined predicate in code, 
or to trap any exception for that matter. 
Replace format/3 with the desired handler:

```
while_running_some_program:-
    catch(foodid(5), 
        error(Err,_Context),
        format('You done goofed! ~w\n', [Err])),
    rest_of_code.
```